# IN magento Navigation show two time in header how to solve it

Tags: magento

How to remove one navigation i will try but not solve it. here below screen short of this error..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7eh0.jpg)

Comment: Clear magento cache or open in browser's private window and then check again.

Comment: OK, So can you tell me after doing which task its showing two times navigation? Did you install any plugin for navigation?

Comment: After install theme its showing two times navigation. when remove below code:-  "  <reference name="top.menu">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.topnav" template="catalog/navigation/top.phtml"/>
        </reference>  "          It show one navigation but not show the proper navigation and design of navigation .

Comment: Please post content of the template phtml file that calls the navigation.

Comment: this  content of top.phtml   --->>>    <?php $_categories = $this->getStoreCategories(); ?>
<?php if(count($_categories)): ?>
<div class="nav-container">
    <div id="custommenu">  
        <?php $level=0; foreach ($_categories as $_category): $level++; if($level == 4){ $level=1;} ?>   
            <?php echo $this->drawCustomMenuItem($_category,$level) ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        <div class="clearBoth"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling code two times in your header.phtml

check that and remove one.

or you can just hide one of them using css property.

just select the class using parent class and assign rule

```
display:none !important;
```